# It is possible to add a value at the end of mysql data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

So, I have this table, where I store some numbers separated by ",". For me, it is ok to store them like this, because when I echo them, I need them in this exact order.

Is there any way through which I can add some numbers at the end of the existing ones?

Here is the table:

```
id | mat_id     | note            |
-----------------------------------
1  | 1          | 1,2,3,4         |
```

I want, through a form, to be able to add a number at the end, as follows:

```
id | mat_id     | note            |
-----------------------------------
1  | 1          | 1,2,3,4,5       |
```

I did not find anything about such thing on google...It would be very useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: db normalisation, dont store your data like this. you say its 'ok' for you, so i think you know you shouldn't be doing it, and then the problem you face is the reason why you shouldn't be doing it

Comment: I agree with Dagon - trust me/us; fix the problem now or life will be more painful than it needs to be later.

Comment: Oke if the data is oke to you  write me an query that can count the number of notes with id = 1 you have 5 minutes to write that query... (real live questions/examples always work best)

Comment: Well time is up if you need this some time http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5282d/2 here it is.

Comment: Sorry, the internet connection failed. Ok, so I understand the problems. Then another question arises. I have a code that already works for now. it echoes the values in a table. If I store the "note" with different ids, is there a way for me to echo them separated by a comma, befor jumping to the next "mat_id"? Should I post another question? Thank you all!

Comment: you could group by mat_id and then use group_concat (note order by id)

Comment: I was reading about this already:) Thanks a lot! You are great guys! I wish I haved the opportunity to buy you all a beer! I`m going to post my question tomorrow, as it is already 2:25 AM here, and I am getting tired (and you can see this by this stupid question ).Thank you all a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often not a good idea to store comma separated values in your columns. But if you really can't change your database structure, you can use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET note = CONCAT_WS(',', note, '5')
```

this will automatically insert a comma after the note if there's some data already, otherwise it will just add the string '5':

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', '1,2,3,4', '5');
1,2,3,4,5

SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', NULL, '5');
5
```

of course, you need to make sure that you are not using empty strings otherwise it will fail:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', '', '5');
,5
```

or it will complicate the query a little:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET note = CONCAT_WS(',', CASE WHEN note<>'' THEN note END, '5')
```

Comment: A bit better, with good mention of the caveat. Still not what I'd call ideal though.

Comment: That empty string gotcha really isn't nice - and if addressed it will make the query a lot more complicated, I guess.

Comment: i feel some questions shouldn't be answered when the original  approach is just 'wrong'; but that that's just me

Comment: @Dagon yes the approach is not correct... I think it's better to specify that in the answer, I've updated it already, tnx

Comment: Thank you all! I decided not to use this. But i ran into another problem ( i explained it in the comments at question)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET note= CONCAT(note, ',5') WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: This is easy to get wrong. The original code left the result as `1,2,3,45`. Not good at all - additional checking/patching are required to make this somewhat consistent wrt the existing values. (So while it will "work" here, it is very touchy and still doesn't represent "well laid out" information.)